# laravel неизвестный и длинный route

Tags: php, laravel

есть таблица с товарами, в ней есть фильтры. Выбирая первый фильтр строится путь `category/filter_1/` выбирая еще 1 фильтр уже на следующей странице - `category/filter_1/filter_2`

Проблема в том, что я не знаю сколько в итоге будет длина роутинга. Есть ли какие либо инструменты в laravel, которые тут могут помочь? Просто подскажите направление

Comment: На мой взгляд, таким методом, очень сложно отследить, что выбрано в фильтре. например выбран 3й параметр, вместо второго, следовательно он уже будет вторым в строке URL, а вы ждете 3й.

Comment: @StereoFlo отследить можно, сеошник ненормальный хочет именно так

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Route::get('category/{url}/filters/{any}', 'AppController@showFilterCategory')->where('any', '.*');
```

И затем в контроллере

```
public function showFilterCategory($url, $any) {
    dd($any);
}
```

Надеюсь кому-то поможет =)

Answer (score 1):

Думаю можно сделать так:

```
Route::get('category/{filters}', 'MyController@myAction');
```

В контроллере:

```
public function myAction($filters)
{
   $filters_array = explode('/', $filters);
}
```

и вы будете иметь масив с списком фильтров

Comment: попробую)) скажу что вышло

Comment: `$filters_array = explode('/', $filters);` Исправьте

Comment: к слову, вариант не работает, а вот Route::get('category/{url}/filters/{any}', 'AppController@showFilterCategory')->where('any', '.*'); оказалось то что нужно, правда на поиски убил часа 4((